# Does there exist a differentiable function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ such that $f([0,1])$ has a non-empty interior?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Does there exist a differentiable function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ such that $f([0,1])$ has a non-empty interior ? I know that such $f$ doesn't exist if I also assume $f$ is $C^1$ . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: Look for Peano curves, or space-filling curves.

Comment: Look up "space-filling curve".

Comment: @DanielFischer : Sorry for the confusion , I originally meant differentiable function . Are there differentiable space-filling curves ?

Comment: No - This was [discussed on MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/201424/proof-that-no-differentiable-space-filling-curve-exists).

Comment: @MarkMcClure : okay , so $f(\mathbb R)$ has $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure 0 .. so inparticular it cannot contain any non-empty open set